# Is the hash-based commitment IND-CPA?

Tags: chosen-plaintext-attack, commitments

As we know the well-known hash-based commitment is as follows:

- Prover: given a message $m$, it:

  (1) picks a fresh random value $r$

  (2) computes $H(r||m)=c$.
- Verifier: given $c$ and the commitment opening: $(r,m)$, checks $H(r||m)=c$

**Question**: Am I right that in the random oracle model, the above scheme is IND-CPA?

Comment: This might help you [The hiding property of commitments is exactly the same as for (CPA-secure) public-key encryption:](https://cs.nyu.edu/courses/fall08/G22.3210-001/lect/lecture14.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

Indistinguishability under chosen message attacks (IND-CPA) is a security definition for encryption schemes and not for commitments. So we cannot claim that a commitment scheme is IND-CPA.

Notice that the above scheme cannot be an encryption since there is no encryption/decryption key. In fact, if the hash function has a larger domain than range, there may be multiple pairs $(m,r)$ that map to the same $c$ and one cannot know which one is the correct (even if they were all powerful).

It is true, however, that the scheme you propose is hiding: for any two messages $m_0,m_1$ it holds that $H(r,m_0)$ and $H(r,m_1)$ are indistinguishable in the random oracle model.

Comment: For hiding property, the hash function should be partial pre-image resistance, not just acting like a random oracle.